# SSIS string array as a variable

Tags: arrays, web-services, variables, ssis

I'm using a web services task in SSIS and it's working okay.  One of the parameters is a string[] array.  I can type type in the values to the editor and it works fine, but I want to load it from a variable.  But I can't figure out how to create/set a string array variable.  I created a string variable and set it to things like {'Test'} or ['Test'], but they didn't work.

Ultimately what I want to do is have it be an expression where some of the strings are other variables.
**ArrayList = @SystemVariable::PackageName, @SystemVariable::TaskName....**

Comment: ArrayList is an SSIS variable of type Object, yes? The only way I can think of to fill that will be a script task.

Comment: Was hoping to avoid that, but does seem to be the only way.  Been working with it just can't quite figure out.

Answer (score 3):

First declare an objcet variable and in script component convert your variable to string array. Finally passing your array to object variable that you declare. 
For example I declare an object variable on package level and in script component I'm passing string array to object variable.

```
string[] liste = Dts.Variables["Receipients"].Value.ToString().Split(',');
Dts.Variables["List"].Value = liste;
```